# SQL injection from form insert

Tags: php, sql, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I'm having trouble understanding how to sanitise php against SQL injection and hope someone would be kind enough to explain to me what I need to change here in order to make my code safe?

```
<?php
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('****', '****', '****', 'db');

$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES ('$_POST[1]', '$_POST[2]', '$_POST[3]')";

if (mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query)) {
echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows($dbConnection) . " row";
} else {
echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLi supports [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), which is better than manually escaping:

Since you are using procedural MySQLi, here is an example:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnection, "INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
{

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $_POST[1], $_POST[2], $_POST[3]);

    /* execute query */
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
    {
        echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows($dbConnection) . " row";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection);
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent SQL injections, you could use prepared statements. You'll need some more `mysqli_` functions for that:

- [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param)
- [`mysqli_stmt_execute()`](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_execute)

With these you can  write something like the following:

```
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('****', '****', '****', 'db');

// prepare the query
$query = mysqli_prepare( $dbConnection, "INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

// bind parameters; 2nd parameter is for data-types
mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $query, "sss", $_POST[1], $_POST[2], $_POST[3] );

// execute query
if ( mysqli_stmt_execute($query) ) {
  echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows($dbConnection) . " row";
} else {
  echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the old mysql_* functions look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
$datapoint1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[1]);
...
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES ('$datapoint1', '$datapoint2', '$datapoint3')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statements or [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)